# Tiny Pe file format program error when running on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, assembly, nasm, portable-executable

I'm trying to run the following assembly code (assembled with Nasm) in Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

```
; tiny.asm

BITS 32

;
; MZ header
;
; The only two fields that matter are e_magic and e_lfanew

mzhdr:
    dw "MZ"                       ; e_magic
    dw 0                          ; e_cblp UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_cp UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_crlc UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_cparhdr UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_minalloc UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_maxalloc UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_ss UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_sp UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_csum UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_ip UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_cs UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_lsarlc UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_ovno UNUSED
    times 4 dw 0                  ; e_res UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_oemid UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; e_oeminfo UNUSED
    times 10 dw 0                 ; e_res2 UNUSED
    dd pesig                      ; e_lfanew

;
; PE signature
;

pesig:
    dd "PE"

;
; PE header
;

pehdr:
    dw 0x014C                     ; Machine (Intel 386)
    dw 1                          ; NumberOfSections
    dd 0x4545BE5D                 ; TimeDateStamp UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; PointerToSymbolTable UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; NumberOfSymbols UNUSED
    dw opthdrsize                 ; SizeOfOptionalHeader
    dw 0x103                      ; Characteristics (no relocations, executable, 32 bit)

;
; PE optional header
;

filealign equ 1
sectalign equ 1

%define round(n, r) (((n+(r-1))/r)*r)

opthdr:
    dw 0x10B                      ; Magic (PE32)
    db 8                          ; MajorLinkerVersion UNUSED
    db 0                          ; MinorLinkerVersion UNUSED
    dd round(codesize, filealign) ; SizeOfCode UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; SizeOfInitializedData UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; SizeOfUninitializedData UNUSED
    dd start                      ; AddressOfEntryPoint
    dd code                       ; BaseOfCode UNUSED
    dd round(filesize, sectalign) ; BaseOfData UNUSED
    dd 0x400000                   ; ImageBase
    dd sectalign                  ; SectionAlignment
    dd filealign                  ; FileAlignment
    dw 4                          ; MajorOperatingSystemVersion UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; MinorOperatingSystemVersion UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; MajorImageVersion UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; MinorImageVersion UNUSED
    dw 4                          ; MajorSubsystemVersion
    dw 0                          ; MinorSubsystemVersion UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; Win32VersionValue UNUSED
    dd round(filesize, sectalign) ; SizeOfImage
    dd round(hdrsize, filealign)  ; SizeOfHeaders
    dd 0                          ; CheckSum UNUSED
    dw 2                          ; Subsystem (Win32 GUI)
    dw 0x400                      ; DllCharacteristics UNUSED
    dd 0x100000                   ; SizeOfStackReserve UNUSED
    dd 0x1000                     ; SizeOfStackCommit
    dd 0x100000                   ; SizeOfHeapReserve
    dd 0x1000                     ; SizeOfHeapCommit UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; LoaderFlags UNUSED
    dd 16                         ; NumberOfRvaAndSizes UNUSED

;
; Data directories
;

    times 16 dd 0, 0

opthdrsize equ $ - opthdr

;
; PE code section
;

    db ".text", 0, 0, 0           ; Name
    dd codesize                   ; VirtualSize
    dd round(hdrsize, sectalign)  ; VirtualAddress
    dd round(codesize, filealign) ; SizeOfRawData
    dd code                       ; PointerToRawData
    dd 0                          ; PointerToRelocations UNUSED
    dd 0                          ; PointerToLinenumbers UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; NumberOfRelocations UNUSED
    dw 0                          ; NumberOfLinenumbers UNUSED
    dd 0x60000020                 ; Characteristics (code, execute, read) UNUSED

hdrsize equ $ - $$

;
; PE code section data
;

align filealign, db 0

code:

; Entry point

start:
    push byte 42
    pop eax
    ret

codesize equ $ - code

filesize equ $ - $$
```

Code taken from: http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/

I create the executable using: **nasm -f bin -o tiny.exe tiny.asm**
But when i'm trying to run the tiny.exe, i get an error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000018).

From the other hand on a Windows XP SP3 machine runs flawlessly. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Antivirus software getting confused?

Comment: Good observation! I tested though with antivirus disabled and got same error. So it must be something else..

Comment: I haven't tracked it all the way down but in ntdll!LdrpWx86ProtectImagePages a call to NtProtectVirtualMemory is called with base address of 0x00400160 and NumberOfBytesToProtect = 0x1000, which spans two pages (which is a problem since the next page is unallocated), if we change base address to 0x00400000 then it is only one page and it loads and executes.  So, some value in the PE Header now results in improper rounding, or they fixed something in Win7 that used to be wrong in XP.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. What tool did you use?

Comment: Just WinDbg and some well placed breakpoints.  Set Event Filters->Create Process to Enabled so it breaks at start-up then set some breakpoints in LdrpInitialize and start stepping through code until if fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
filealign equ 1
sectalign equ 1
```

The Windows 7 loader does not accept filealign less than <s>512</s> and sectionalign less than <s>4096</s>.

**Edit:**

In the light of [counter](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=61246) [examples](https://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/browse/trunk/src/PE/tinyW7_3264.asm), it seems that the alignment limits are 4/4.

Comment: Oh i see..thanks! Is there a reference where i can read about Windows 7 PE loader?

Comment: Not that I know of, I don't believe it's very documented :)

Comment: I change the values of filealign to 0x200 and sectalign to 0x1000, and now i get the message: tiny.exe not a valid Win32 application ! It seems there is an error that remains...Do you believe that the round macro is wrong?

Comment: @Ponty Even though there are equs for both aligns, the code isn't made to support arbitrary numbers for them. I suggest you study a less aggressive example if you're keen on learning about the PE format.

Comment: @Jens Björnhager How can I make the round macro to support arbitrary numbers for align values?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the macro, it's where and how it's used, resulting in wrong values in the header. I had to change quite a lot to get it to run on w7: http://files.sys5.se/tinype.asm

Comment: I doubt this is correct. Don't 4k demos still work? Many of them have `e_lfanew = 4` to overlap the MZ and PE headers, which also forces section alignment to 4 (because that field coincides with `e_lfanew`). I also can't find a mention of Win7 not accepting low alignment PE-COFFs in corkami's docs.

Comment: 4ks usually set the code section to overlap the headers completely and use only one section, so the need for low aligns is alleviated. I don't know about programs using e_lfanew=4 working or not, but a lot of programs that used to work doesn't anymore. I just looked at a recent 4k, and it uses e_lfanew=12, sectionalignment=65536 and filealignment=512.

Comment: After a bit of searching, I found this one: [Kacce](http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=61246). I'm not running Windows, but I hope you can check whether it works.

Comment: @JensBjörnhager: and I just found [an example of a low alignment binary](https://code.google.com/p/corkami/source/browse/trunk/src/PE/tinyW7_3264.asm) which should work on Windows 7. Combined with the fact that the other answer is written by Ange Albertini himself, I'm willing to bet that this answer is wrong and his is correct.

Comment: Kacce actually seems to use 4/4 as alignments, as does the other example. This goes against my own experience, but it may mean that W7 accepts alignments no lower than 4/4. Will have to research this some more.

Answer (score 4):

Windows XP has smaller requirements in size than Vista or later:
it accepts a truncated OptionalHeader while later Windows version reject the file if it's not complete.

Thus, you just need to add padding to make it work under Vista or later.

see [my PE page on Corkami](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE?show=content#minimal_sizes) for more details and examples, with sources and binaries.

(this has absolutely nothing to do with alignments)